# error al correr server.js Node js

Tags: nodejs

Hola gente estoy haciendo una aplicacion Node JS y me suelta este error alguien sabe porque si tengo bien instalado el node JS,npm y express?

```html
root@sommer-AO532h:/home/sommer/Desktop/aplicacionnode/express_example# DEBUG=express_example:* npm start
> application-name@0.0.1 start /home/sommer/Desktop/aplicacionnode/express_example
> nodejs ./bin/www

events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1237:14)
    at listen (net.js:1273:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1369:5)
    at Function.app.listen (/home/sommer/Desktop/aplicacionnode/express_example/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:531:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/sommer/Desktop/aplicacionnode/express_example/bin/www:7:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)

npm ERR! Linux 4.8.0-54-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! application-name@0.0.1 start: `nodejs ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the application-name@0.0.1 start script 'nodejs ./bin/www'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the application-name package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     nodejs ./bin/www
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs application-name
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls application-name
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/sommer/Desktop/aplicacionnode/express_example/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 3):

La clave está aquí:

> Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000

Ese mensaje te está indicando que el puerto `3000` está en uso por otro programa.

Puedes:

- Cambiar el puerto en el que ejecutas tu aplicación.
- Averiguar quién lo está usando, y detenerlo o cambiar su configuración.

Para ver quién lo está usando, puedes hacer

> sudo lsof -i :3000

Para detenerlo, pues depende. Si es un servicio o *daemon* del sistema, un

> sudo service XXX stop

debería de bastar. A unas malas, puedes igualmente hacer

> sudo kill -9 PID-DEL-PROGRAMA

El PID lo obtienes con la anterior orden `lsof`.

Esta última opción, `kill`, **NO ES RECOMENDABLE** a menos que sepas **muy bien** lo que estas haciendo.

Answer (score 1):

Imagino que estas usando express generator o algún ejemplo ya realizado, así que busca la carpeta **bin** y dentro encontraras un archivo llamado **www**
ábrelo con cualquier editor y busca la linea:

```
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
```

Modifica el **3000** por otro numero y ya te funcionará. Tu error es que intentas usar el puerto 3000 y según te indica la consola ya lo tienes en uso:

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
```

Por ejemplo puedes dejarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '4870');
```

Si no tienes la carpeta **bin** en tu archivo principal (por norma general app.js) busca esta linea o si no añadela:

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

Y lo mismo que antes, cambia el 3000 por otro puerto