# Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, windows, npm

Qué tal, tengo un server ejecutándose

`const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;`

desde hace ya varias semanas y nunca había experimentado problemas con el sino hasta hoy, sucede que de manera intercalada cuando lo inicio me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

`Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3001`.

Ahora bien, no se si esté relacionado pero el error persiste desde que instale los siguientes módulos por npm:
bcryptjs, cors, helmet  y jsonwebtoken.
¿Alguien tiene idea de a que se deba?, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Me olvidaba, ya intenté repetidas veces cerrar el servidor con ctrl+c en el terminal pero aún asi el problema persiste, creo que requiere medidas más drásticas

Comment: [Pregunta relacionada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/76864/error-al-correr-server-js-node-js/185466#185466)

Comment: La respuesta contiene comandos para Linux, en mi caso estoy usando windows

Comment: Revisa [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-tcp-or-udp-port-on-windows/48199#48199), está en inglés, pero te permitirá saber qué servicio o programa está usando el puerto en cuestión. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logre solucionarlo en su momento finalizando todos los procesos relacionados a Node en el administrador de tareas, asimismo recomiendo cerrar y volver a abrir el editor de texto que se esté utilizando para asegurar el correcto funcionamiento.